# How to add an onBlur event keeping the original?

Tags: javascript, onblur

I have a code that is basically like this:

```
<input type="text" value="" onfocus="myFunction(this);" onblur="alert('1');">

<script>
  function myFunction(obj) {
    obj.onblur = function() {
      alert("2");
    };
  }
</script>
```

How can I do to run the original onBlur event, after the event added for my function?

**-- EDIT --**
That's my function: http://jsbin.com/pucaz/1

Comment: why are you adding another function to `onblur` event?

Comment: @SumanBogati I am creating a function for masking, formatting and validation. The validation is done on the onBlur event. I just do a validation to see if the value is correct. But other developers may need to make, for example, a comparison of the value entered in the field, with some other.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rely on traditional event registering, you can do something like this:

```
function myFunction(obj) {
    var newonblur = function() {
        alert("2");
    }, oldonblur = obj.onblur;
    obj.onblur = oldonblur ? function(e) {
        oldonblur(e);
        newonblur(e);
    } : newonblur;
}
```

But I don't recomment doing so. Use a more modern approach with `addEventListener` and be happy with it. If you need to support older browsers, consider using some framework like jQuery.

Comment: I tried to use the function you showed, but it did not work. Neither alerts were called.

How to `addEventListener` method, it does not work very well when the function is called by the onFocus event. Only if I create a Regular Expression to remove the myFunction function in the onFocus event. 
If all else fails, I'll adopt it. Thank you.

Comment: @JúlioPradera Sorry, I was distracted in the middle of editing. Check now.

Comment: Its function creates the same effect and hence the same "problem" that the addEventListener. I'll apply it with Regular Expression, but I remain open to see if anyone has any more lightweight solution. :)
Thank you very much.

Comment: @JúlioPradera Let me get this straight: you need to validate the input after the input field blurs, and throw an alert if the check fails? If it's so, you don't need an `onfocus` event listener at all: just perform the check with `onblur`.

Comment: I use the onFocus event to start all. My function is too big. :) I use onKeyDown, onPaste and onBlur.

Comment: @JúlioPradera Ok, but I still don't get why you need `onfocus`. `onkeydown`, `onpaste` and `onblur` events fire on the element only if the element is focused, so `onfocus` is redundant. Remember that those properties yield a *reference* to the function, so "my function is too big" is not an issue. If you could show more of your code, maybe I could give a more precise answer.

Comment: @JúlioPradera I'll review the code later - but in the meanwhile edit your question and put the link to your jsbin there too.